# Source Code Retrieval

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I worked on the Lightning Component framework as part of my cursus. I have a need to write down my sources from my app. Is there a way to have a readable document with all these ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to download the source of the components you wrote? Or you want the Source of the Whole Lightning Component Framework?

Comment: I want to download the source of the components I wrote. As for the framework, I think I can make a link to the github.

Comment: I wrote quite a few components, it would save me some time and efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the Force.com CLI:

https://force-cli.heroku.com/

You can login to your org and do things like:

**force fetch Aura**

This will retrieve all of the Lightning Components, each in it's own folder and with nice filenames.

Comment: Quite amazing. This was a bit hard to make it work as I had a little bit of experience. And indeed the filenames are nice.

Comment: `force-cli.heroku.com` is not available anymore (